# select on one result from the query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to query a few tables in our db that contains product data. It is a MSSQL 2005 database.  The problem is its returning multiple rows for one product when I need it to only produce one row per product.  Blow is the query and results I'm using.

```
SELECT      ProductItem.sku, ProductItem.title, ProductItem.short_desc, ProductItem.long_desc, ProductItem.active, ProductItem.product_item_id, 
                    ProductCategory.category_desc, ProductCategoryMap.product_id, ProductCategory.active AS activecat, Product.adwords_label, 
                    ProductItem.item_price, ProductItem.sale_price
FROM          Product INNER JOIN
                        ProductCategoryMap INNER JOIN
                        ProductCategory ON ProductCategoryMap.product_category_id = ProductCategory.product_category_id ON 
                        Product.product_id = ProductCategoryMap.product_id FULL OUTER JOIN
                        ProductItem ON Product.product_key = ProductItem.sku
WHERE      (ProductItem.active = 1) AND (ProductCategory.active = 1)
```

This returns the following results:[image]

I know the problem occurs because the product resides in multiple categories, but really I don't need every category its in, just one of them. So ideally just one product for every row returned

I can't figure out how to make my query achieve that though.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: If there are multiple categories for a product and you are selecting the category_desc in the select list. Which category you want to display or you don't care which one is displayed?

Comment: For this project, I don't care which one is displayed.

Comment: My response is most similar to KMs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, take category columns out and add DISTINCT. You've asked for "category" so you can get all categories.

Also:

- the WHERE changes your FULL OUTER JOIN to an INNER
- get product_id from Product
- the activecat column is implied by the where clause anyway

I've tweaked it for clarity and added an aggregate to get one category

```
SELECT
   PI.sku, PI.title, PI.short_desc, PI.long_desc, 
   PI.active, PI.product_item_id, 
   PI.item_price, PI.sale_price, 

   MIN(PC.category_desc),
   P.product_id,
   1 AS activecat, --implied by filter

   P.adwords_label
FROM 
    ProductItem PI
    INNER JOIN
    Product P ON P.product_key = PI.sku
    INNER JOIN
    ProductCategoryMap PCM ON P.product_id = PCM.product_id
    INNER JOIN
    ProductCategory PC ON PCM.product_category_id = PC.product_category_id
WHERE
   (PI.active = 1) AND (PC.active = 1)
GROUP BY
   PI.sku, PI.title, PI.short_desc, PI.long_desc, 
   PI.active, PI.product_item_id, 
   PI.item_price, PI.sale_price, 
   P.product_id,
   P.adwords_label
```

Edit: you can tidy it more with APPLY which will also deal with *no* categories if changed to OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT
   PI.sku, PI.title, PI.short_desc, PI.long_desc, 
   PI.active, PI.product_item_id, 
   PI.item_price, PI.sale_price, 

   PC2.category_desc,
   P.product_id,
   PC2.active AS activecat,

   P.adwords_label
FROM 
    ProductItem PI
    INNER JOIN
    Product P ON P.product_key = PI.sku
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT TOP 1
        PC.category_desc, PC.active
    FROM
        ProductCategoryMap PCM
        INNER JOIN
        ProductCategory PC ON PCM.product_category_id = PC.product_category_id
    WHERE
       P.product_id = PCM.product_id AND PC.active = 1
    ORDER BY 
       PC.category_desc
    ) PC2
WHERE
   PI.active = 1
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I would do that...BUT I need to grab at least one category for this project.

Comment: Awesome, worked great.  I'm no sql guru and wouldn't have figured this out without your help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends a bit upon what you want.

If you only care about product category for the sake of asking "does this product have at least 1 active category?"  Your query would look like ...

```
SELECT      DISTINCT
            ProductItem.sku, 
            ProductItem.title, 
            ProductItem.short_desc, 
            ProductItem.long_desc, 
            ProductItem.active, 
            ProductItem.product_item_id, 
            ProductCategoryMap.product_id, 
            Product.adwords_label, 
            ProductItem.item_price, 
            ProductItem.sale_price
FROM      
            Product 
INNER JOIN  ProductCategoryMap   ON Product.product_id = ProductCategoryMap.product_id 
INNER JOIN  ProductCategory     ON ProductCategoryMap.product_category_id = ProductCategory.product_category_id 
FULL JOIN   ProductItem         ON Product.product_key = ProductItem.sku
WHERE      
            (ProductItem.active = 1) AND 
            (ProductCategory.active = 1)
```

If you don't care about category at all it would look like ....

```
SELECT      
            ProductItem.sku, 
            ProductItem.title, 
            ProductItem.short_desc, 
            ProductItem.long_desc, 
            ProductItem.active, 
            ProductItem.product_item_id, 
            ProductCategoryMap.product_id, 
            Product.adwords_label, 
            ProductItem.item_price, 
            ProductItem.sale_price
FROM      
            Product 
INNER JOIN  ProductCategoryMap  ON Product.product_id = ProductCategoryMap.product_id 
ProductCategory.product_category_id 
FULL JOIN   ProductItem         ON Product.product_key = ProductItem.sku
WHERE      
            (ProductItem.active = 1)
```

If you want to include active category names as a CSV list (just mind the execution plan if this is a large result set) ....

```
SELECT      ProductItem.sku, 
            ProductItem.title, 
            ProductItem.short_desc, 
            ProductItem.long_desc, 
            ProductItem.active, 
            ProductItem.product_item_id, 
            ProductCategory.category_desc, 
            ProductCategoryMap.product_id, 
            ProductCategory.active AS activecat, 
            Product.adwords_label, 
            ProductItem.item_price, 
            ProductItem.sale_price,
            (SELECT substring((SELECT ( ', ' + CAST(PC.category_desc AS varchar(50)))
                                FROM    ProductCategory PC
                                WHERE   PC.product_category_id =  ProductCategoryMap.product_category_id AND
                                        PC.active = 1
                                FOR XML PATH( '' )
                              ), 3, 8000 )  
                   )      AS    ProductCategoriesCSV
FROM      
            Product 
INNER JOIN  ProductCategoryMap  ON Product.product_id = ProductCategoryMap.product_id 
INNER JOIN  ProductCategory     ON ProductCategoryMap.product_category_id = ProductCategory.product_category_id 
FULL JOIN   ProductItem         ON Product.product_key = ProductItem.sku
WHERE      
            (ProductItem.active = 1)
```

HTH,
-eric

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
SELECT      
  I.sku, 
  I.title, 
  I.short_desc, 
  I.long_desc, 
  I.active, 
  I.product_item_id, 
  T.category_desc, 
  P.product_id, 
  T.active AS activecat, 
  P.adwords_label, 
  I.item_price, 
  I.sale_price
FROM          
  Product P

  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1
      C.category_desc,
      C.active AS activecat
    FROM
      ProductCategoryMap CM 

      INNER JOIN ProductCategory C
      ON CM.product_category_id = C.product_category_id 
    WHERE
      P.product_id = CM.product_id
      AND 
     (C.active = 1)
  ) T

  FULL OUTER JOIN ProductItem I
  ON P.product_key = I.sku
WHERE 
 (I.active = 1)
```